# how to change custom option price by query in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have 32000 products in Magento,

When I added them I have set custom option attribute to products they work perfectly, but now I want to change the price of custom option attribute of all products.

[image]

Is there any way to change price by query or any other tricks ??

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$magePath = 'app/Mage.php'; 

require_once $magePath;

Varien_Profiler::enable(); 

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$product_ids = array(2);
//Product Id = 2, you can use any product id
$productmodel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) { 

/**i use this two arrays for collecte value because i uses inside setData of 
current option*/

$cos=array();
$co=array();

$product = $productmodel->load($product_id);

$options = $product->getProductOptionsCollection();

if (isset($options)) { 

foreach ($options as $o) { 

$title = $o->getTitle();

/**
this block is for changing information of specific option from collection options inside
current product
the save method for this option in end of code
*/

if ($title == "Line 1/Front") { 

$o->setProduct($product); 

$o->setTitle("Line 1/Ftont"); 

$o->setType("drop_down"); 

$o->setIsRequire(1);

$o->setSortOrder(0);


}

/**
this block for update or add information of specific value inside current option
*/

$optionType = $o->getType(); 

//test type

if ($optionType == "drop_down") { 

//getting collection of value related to current option

$values = $o->getValuesCollection(); 

$found = false; 

foreach ($values as $k => $v) { 

//test existing of value for update

if (1 == preg_match("/said$/i", $v->getTitle())) { 

//update and save

$v->setTitle("morad")

->setSku("kk")

->setPriceType("fixed")

->setSortOrder(0)

->setPrice(floatval(13.0000));

$v->setOption($o)->save();

/**
this ligne is important i collecte all value required for normalize save function 
related to current option
*/

$cos[]=$v->toArray($co);

} 
} 


/**
create new value object you can use $option->getValueInstance() for working with 
getSingleton
*/

$value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value'); 

$value->setOption($o) 

->setTitle('valueiwant') 

->setSku("nn")

->setPriceType("fixed")

->setSortOrder(1)

->setPrice(12)

/**
this ligne is important (relation forigien key) for related this new value
to specific option
*/

->setOptionId($o->getId());

$value->save();

/**
this ligne is important i collecte all value required for normalize save function   
related to current option
*/

$cos[]=$value->toArray($co);
} 


$o->setData("values",$cos)->save();

//var_dump($cos);

}


}
}
```

Comment: where i have to put this code ?? and  $values[$v->getId()]['price']= 23; what is 23 here can you explain me please ?

Comment: You can do it programmatically if you wish too, by putting the file on root:

<?php
 
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

Comment: Update my answer now the file will work on root

Comment: $values[$v->getId()]['price']= 23  what is 23 here ??

Comment: I have updated my code copy a paste this on root, and check your product whose product id is passed in it. First create a test product and hit the file url so that you can understand better

Comment: i have most of configurable product is it will work ??

Comment: I am not sure, I have checked this for simple product, you may need to update the code as per your requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16000/discussion-between-dp4solve-and-tbi-infotech).